# Java + Lombok + Guava + Validation

Tags: java, guava, lombok

I have this Pojo:

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Order {

    public enum OrderType {
        BUY, SELL
    }
    private Id id;
    private Quantity quantity;
    private Money price;
    private OrderType orderType;

    public Order(Id id, Quantity quantity, Money price, OrderType orderType) {

        Preconditions.checkNotNull(id, "id can't be null");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(quantity, "quantity can't be null");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(price, "price can't be null");
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(orderType, "orderType can't be null");

        this.id = id;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.orderType = orderType;
    }
```

I wish to do three things:

- use @AllArgsConstructor instead
- and remove the constructor
- but of course keep the Preconditions

Is this possible?

I also like to use @Builder pattern, can I incorporate Preconditions with this approach?

Comment: The use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` could fit your case (see: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark all fields with `@lombok.NonNull` and use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`; that should do it.